# Getting error - Cannot find module 'webpack-core/lib/ReplaceSource' while running ng serve --open

Tags: angular

I am getting the following error when I am trying to run the command - "ng serve --open" in Visual Studio Code. What Might I be missing?[Cannot find module 'webpack-core/lib/ReplaceSource'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiVdW.png)

Comment: Have you installed npm packages properly?

Comment: Yes, I am sure that's not the problem.